# Page is empty when deploy create-react-app build folder by nginx?

Tags: deployment, create-react-app

I just put the build folder to the root folder of nginx server, e.g. `/var/www/html`, but nothing is visible. 
When inspect from browser, the `root` content is empty?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay0gF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your [developer console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) for possible errors. You can also use [React Developer Tools](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/01/02/react-chrome-developer-tools.html) to debug your app. You can provide your non-sensitive code to make us understand it better.

Comment: everything is running well with ```npm start``` in development mode.  so I checked any difference between development and production, and found sonething with routes in production mode. Now it's OK. :) Thank you!